# Running lxde in fullscreen in GNURoot Debian

Tags: lxde, tightvnc, gnuroot

I am trying to run LXDE on GNURoot Debian on Android.
GNURoot Debian uses XTightVNCServer to provide an X environment over VNC, which I can connect to using RealVNC. But when I try to start LXDE using `DISPLAY=localhost:51 startlxde` it starts LXDE in a window. Also the LXDE panel is in a separate window.
What do I need to do to get it running in full screen, so that it acts as a regular desktop environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself. Apparently the XTightVNCServer automatically started an instance of the `twm` window manager, that I didn't notice. When I now started LXDE it was only started as a window in twm.

As it seems, if you start two window managers, the second one is started only as a window in the first one.

So stopping twm before starting LXDE did the trick for me.